# searching values from one dataframe in another dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, columnsorting

I have two datasets, patient data and disease data.
The patient dataset has diseases written in alphanumeric code format which I want to search in the disease dataset to display the disease name.

Patient dataset snapshot[image]

Disease dataset snapshot

[image]

I want use groupby function on the ICD column and find out the occurrence of a disease and rank it in descending order to display the top 5. I have been trying to find a reference for the same, but could not.

Would appreciate the help!

EDIT!!

```
avg2 = joined.groupby('disease_name').TIME_DELTA.mean().disease_name.value_counts()
```

I am getting this error "'Series' object has no attribute 'disease_name'"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data you have are in two pandas dataframes called `patients` and `diseases` and that the diseases dataset has the column names `disease_id` and `disease_name` this could be a solution:

```py
joined = patients.merge(diseases, left_on='ICD', right_on='disease_id')

top_5 = joined.disease_name.value_counts().head(5)
```

This solution joins the data together and then use value_counts instead of grouping. It should solve what I preceive to be what you are asking for even if it is not exactly the functionality you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does work. I wanted to use groupby function because I also have a column with "number days in hospital". So once I have the top 5 diseases, I can then get the average number days the patient spent in the hospital.